# unidentified reference to glutInit

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glew, freeglut

I tried to compile a basic OpenGL program, simply just a blank window.
I'm using CodeLite with the g++ compiler on Linux Mint 18.1 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

The code so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

At first my compiler (G++ in CodeLite) gave the error

```
/home/USER/Projects/CodeLite/Graphical/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `glutInit'
```

I downloaded all the up to date GLEW and GLUT includes from their respective websites and unpacked them to /usr/include/GL, [I edited the project settings linker like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysYBW.png)

Now it gives the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: No, you need to install the library, not just the header files.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk How would I do that apart from the answer Tom gave below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the libraries from the package manager instead: `libglew-dev`, `freeglut3-dev`, `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libglu1-mesa-dev`. The includes and binary files will be placed in the appropriate location.

If the linker cannot find the .so files, locate them with dpkg -L freeglut3-dev and add this directory in the linker command line

```
g++ -L/path/to/libglut.so *.o -o programname
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it didn't install or upgrade anything, I already had them. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Updated my post. On Ubuntu the library binaries go to /usr/lib/ which is in the PATH. Try installing the two other packages. In general it is much better to install the packages than files manually. It is easier to update, and maintain in general.

Comment: @Fons did you compile the library?

Comment: And the good thing with installing the package is that the binaries are provided.

Comment: @Tom Either the 2 other libraries or the full path has helped, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it works. You can test by removing the parameter in the command line and tell us the result.